# Can I copy a CD in Windows 7 without 3rd party software?

Tags: windows-7, compact-disc

Does Windows 7 have a function to copy CDs?

I know I can rip data CDs by just copying their contents to a folder, and audio CDs using the Media Player.

I know I can write data CDs directly through Windows Explorer, and audio CDs through the media player.

Is there any built-in way to copy a CD in Windows 7?  If so, how?

Answer (score 3):

No, Windows 7 cannot, on its own, copy a disc.

Check out [this post](http://www.windowsbbs.com/windows-7/92234-copy-cd-rom-windows-7-without-3rd-party-software.html) for a bunch of suggestions.  I've had good luck personally with [ImgBurn](http://www.imgburn.com/) which is free and powerful.

Comment: ImgBurn has the disadvantage that it doesn't have a 1-step copy.  It requires you to rip and then burn in two steps, each of which require you to know appropriate formats.

Comment: I like CDBurner XP....http://cdburnerxp.se/